# What do "the Dude sporting" and "PR dream come true" mean?

Tags: meaning, slang, colloquialisms

What does this sentence exactly mean?

> The image of the Dude sporting both a Rolex and the Berlin
>   Philharmonic is a PR dream-come-true.

Comment: Absolutely nothing, out of context.

Comment: It sounds like an out-of-context joke from Family Guy... also why is "dude" capitalized?

Comment: You got a fantastic answer, you were lucky, next time please use a dictionary and share your research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Dude**, in [the context](http://www.theguardian.com/music/tomserviceblog/2015/mar/10/berlin-philharmonic-next-principal-conductor) you've taken this from, is Gustavo Dudamel.  As he has a reputation for being quite cool, charismatic and youthful.  He is also appears to be [sponsored by](http://www.rolex.com/world-of-rolex/the-arts.html) **Rolex**.  The Berlin Philharmonic is rated as one of the [best in Europe](http://www.playbillarts.com/news/article/5381.html), if not the world, and is traditionally one of the most appealing for exciting conductors.

Hence, the combination of Dudamel, Rolex and the Berlin Phil is a combination that is very appealing for PR (public relations) purposes, i.e a "**dream-come-true**"

Additionally, "**sporting**" in this context means "*to display or wear, usually ostentatiously*", according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sport).

> 4. Gustavo Dudamel Age: 33 Current job: Music Director, Los Angeles Philharmonic Orchestra Berlin Phil Top Trump rating: 5/10
>
> The image of the Dude sporting both a Rolex and the Berlin
>   Philharmonic is a PR dream-come-true. But Dudamel is more than a
>   plaything of the classical music world, and his work in Los Angeles,
>   where he’s extending his repertoire and the reach of the orchestra is
>   probably exactly what he needs for the next few years. The jump to
>   Berlin could prove too vertiginous at this stage. Like Nelsons, he
>   will surely be in the frame when the Berliners next need a new person
>   at the helm.